# Can't load dynamic dropdown in a Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I'm learning JavaScript and can't solve a simple issue, not sure what I'm missing.

I have a Bootstrap modal where I want to dynamically append currency codes and display them in a dropdown. It works fine outside of bootstrap modal but it doesn't append options inside the modal.

This is the JavaScript code:

```
 var select = document.getElementById("selectCurrencyDefault");
        console.log(select);
        var currencySelection = ["AED","AFN","ALL","AMD","ANG","AOA","ARS","AUD","AWG","AZN","BAM","BBD","BDT","BGN","BHD","BIF","BMD","BND","BOB","BRL","BSD","BTN","BWP","BYN","BZD","CAD","CDF","CHF","CLP","CNY","COP","CRC","CUP","CVE","CZK","DJF","DKK","DOP","DZD","EGP","ERN","ETB","EUR","FJD","FKP","FOK","GBP","GEL","GGP","GHS","GIP","GMD","GNF","GTQ","GYD","HKD","HNL","HRK","HTG","HUF","IDR","ILS","IMP","INR","IQD","IRR","ISK","JEP","JMD","JOD","JPY","KES","KGS","KHR","KID","KMF","KRW","KWD","KYD","KZT","LAK","LBP","LKR","LRD","LSL","LYD","MAD","MDL","MGA","MKD","MMK","MNT","MOP","MRU","MUR","MVR","MWK","MXN","MYR","MZN","NAD","NGN","NIO","NOK","NPR","NZD","OMR","PAB","PEN","PGK","PHP","PKR","PLN","PYG","QAR","RON","RSD","RUB","RWF","SAR","SBD","SCR","SDG","SEK","SGD","SHP","SLE","SOS","SRD","SSP","STN","SYP","SZL","THB","TJS","TMT","TND","TOP","TRY","TTD","TVD","TWD","TZS","UAH","UGX","USD","UYU","UZS","VES","VND","VUV","WST","XAF","XCD","XDR","XOF","XPF","YER","ZAR","ZMW","ZWL"];

            for(var i = 0; i < currencySelection.length; i++) {
                var opt = currencySelection[i];
                var el = document.createElement("option");
                el.setAttribute("id", "options");
                el.textContent = opt;
                // el.value = opt;
                select.appendChild(el);
            }
```

This is HTML code (dropdown within the modal):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Settings</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">


<div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Default Currency:
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" id = "selectCurrencyDefault" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                 
                </div>
              </div>

</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to append a simple link to the modal and it worked but doesn't seem to work when I add Javascript.
I added z-index to CSS as well and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You added the tag `bootstrap-5` to your question so I assume you are loading in the scripts for bootstrap V5.3, however your bootstrap HTML is not that of V5, likely V4.

When you change the HTML to proper bootstrap V5, your code works just fine:

```js
var select = document.getElementById("selectCurrencyDefault");
//console.log(select);
var currencySelection = ["AED", "AFN", "ALL", "AMD", "ANG", "AOA", "ARS", "AUD", "AWG", "AZN", "BAM", "BBD", "BDT", "BGN", "BHD", "BIF", "BMD", "BND", "BOB", "BRL", "BSD", "BTN", "BWP", "BYN", "BZD", "CAD", "CDF", "CHF", "CLP", "CNY", "COP", "CRC", "CUP", "CVE", "CZK", "DJF", "DKK", "DOP", "DZD", "EGP", "ERN", "ETB", "EUR", "FJD", "FKP", "FOK", "GBP", "GEL", "GGP", "GHS", "GIP", "GMD", "GNF", "GTQ", "GYD", "HKD", "HNL", "HRK", "HTG", "HUF", "IDR", "ILS", "IMP", "INR", "IQD", "IRR", "ISK", "JEP", "JMD", "JOD", "JPY", "KES", "KGS", "KHR", "KID", "KMF", "KRW", "KWD", "KYD", "KZT", "LAK", "LBP", "LKR", "LRD", "LSL", "LYD", "MAD", "MDL", "MGA", "MKD", "MMK", "MNT", "MOP", "MRU", "MUR", "MVR", "MWK", "MXN", "MYR", "MZN", "NAD", "NGN", "NIO", "NOK", "NPR", "NZD", "OMR", "PAB", "PEN", "PGK", "PHP", "PKR", "PLN", "PYG", "QAR", "RON", "RSD", "RUB", "RWF", "SAR", "SBD", "SCR", "SDG", "SEK", "SGD", "SHP", "SLE", "SOS", "SRD", "SSP", "STN", "SYP", "SZL", "THB", "TJS", "TMT", "TND", "TOP", "TRY", "TTD", "TVD", "TWD", "TZS", "UAH", "UGX", "USD", "UYU", "UZS", "VES", "VND", "VUV", "WST", "XAF", "XCD", "XDR", "XOF", "XPF", "YER", "ZAR", "ZMW", "ZWL"];

for (var i = 0; i < currencySelection.length; i++) {
  var opt = currencySelection[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.setAttribute("id", "options");
  el.textContent = opt;
  // el.value = opt;
  select.appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Settings</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Default Currency:
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" id="selectCurrencyDefault">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```